# if-else statements in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<% form_for :customer, :url => {:action => :save_order} do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>

<%= f.label :"Select Payment Method" %>
<%= f.select :payment_method, [['Cash','cash'],['Credit Card','credit card']] %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :customer_first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
</p>


<p>
    <%= f.label :customer_last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
</p>


<p>
    <%= f.label :email_address %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
</p>
    <% if @customer.payment_method == "Credit Card" %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :credit_card %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :credit_card_number %>
</p>

  <% else %>
  <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Place Order"%>
```

Here's my code. I just want the credit card number field to appear when the user selects credit card as their payment method. But when i select credit card in the drop down menu nothing happens. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` statement will run server side, but you need client side logic to respond to the change in the drop-down list. You could show the credit card 'p' regardless, but hide it initially via CSS, then have some jQuery similar to this -

```
$("payment_method").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "credit card") $(".creditcard").show();
})
```

Comment: how do i do that? I'm new to rails.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Javascript to handle this problem. What you are trying is not working because the code is parsed server-side once.

Here is a Railscast which is dealing with a simmilar Problem:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus

You can transfer the techniques to your problem.